# How do I make my iPhone ring for phone calls but be silent for email?

Tags: ios, notifications

As a newbie on an iPhone 5, please how do I set up my phone to give an audible ringtone when I get a phone call, but remain silent when I get an email?

Answer (score 7):

Open up Settings > Notification Center > Mail, then change the Alert Sound to None. This will silence any sounds when you get an email.

By default phone calls make a sound, so there is nothing you need to change for that.

Answer (score -3):

I found that the small switch just top the left of the volume controls on the side of the phone was showing red and so off. move the switch and the audible ringtone etc will sound.

Comment: This will also allow emails to make a tone, which isn't wanted in this scenario.